# Different features give the same Accuracy in SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, hyperparameters

For a classification task I try to compare two models (with SVM)  where the difference between the models is just one feature (namely, *cult_distance & inst_dist*). Even after HP-tuning (using GridSearchCV) both models show the exact same accuracy. When I try a third model with both *cult_distance & inst_dist* in the model, still the exact same accuracy. My code is below and in the screenshot you see the classification report. As you can see in the report, the minority class is not predicted. I think my model is overfitting but I don't know how to solve this. Note: also when I run the model without any other features than *cult_distance & inst_dist*, the accuracy is still the same.

```
features1 = ['inst_dist', 'cult_distance', 'deal_numb', 'acq_sic', 'acq_stat', 'acq_form',
       'tar_sic', 'tar_stat', 'tar_form', 'vendor_name', 'pay_method',
       'advisor', 'stake', 'deal_value', 'days', 'sic_sim']
X = data.loc[:, features1]
y = data.loc[:, ['deal_status']]

### training the model

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1, train_size = .75)

# defining parameter range 

rfc = svm.SVC(random_state = 0)

param_grid = {'C': [0.001], 
              'gamma': ['auto'],
              'kernel': ['rbf'],
             'degree':[1]} 

grid = GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid = param_grid, refit = True, verbose = 2,n_jobs=-1) 
   
# fitting the model for grid search 
grid.fit(X_train, y_train) 
 
# print best parameter after tuning  
grid_predictions = grid.predict(X_test) 
   
# print classification report 
print(classification_report(y_test, grid_predictions))
```

[image: The output of the classification report]

EDIT: After a useful comment, I used class_weight to insert in the dataset. However the accuracy of the data is much lower than the baseline of 0.76?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be connected with unbalanced dataset. One class present much more in your dataset, so model learns to predict only that class. There are numerous ways to combat that, the simplest one is to adjust `class_weight` parameter in your model. In your situation it should be around `class_weight = {0 : 3.2, 1 : 1}` as second class is 3 times more popular. You can calculate that using [`compute_class_weight`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) from sklearn.

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I try to insert the `class_weight` in the fit model: `clf.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight = class_weights)`, it returns the error: TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_weight'. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: You should pass it to model parameters, like that `svm.SVC(random_state = 0, class_weight = {0 : 3.2, 1 : 1})`. More on how to use it in [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn-svm-svc)

Comment: I figured that out, thanks! My model has a much lower accuracy (0,40), then before. Any ideas how to improve to possibly beat the baseline (0.76)? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: So how does your classification report looks now?

Comment: I've edited the question with the classification report!